# InstallAnywhere installer won't work on Windows 7 64bit when run from the system user

Tags: installanywhere

We have an application that runs as a windows service.  As it's running, it will check with a flexnet server to see if there is an update.  If there is, then the update is downloaded, the service is stopped, and the update is installed.  This updater was created with InstallAnywhere 2010.  Everything is working fine except when this runs on Windows 7 64bit (we believe the same thing happens on any 64bit version of Windows).  Everything works fine on Windows 7 32bit.

When the problem occurs, the update is successfully downloaded from flexnet.  It executes, and unpacks the installation files to C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\.  Then it runs the installation executable that was just unpacked.  That executable, however, throws up an error dialog saying "LaunchAnywhere: cannot locate executable".  That executable acts like it can't find the files that were unpacked with it.

Again, on 32bit there's no problem.  Also, we can run the same process while logged in as a user (program is running in user mode instead of as a service).  It uses that user's temp directory, and everything works fine.  The problem only happens when on a 64bit system, while running as a service (system user).

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Did you build it for a 64 bit OS as well?

Answer (score 0):

<[image]>

Did you have this step targeting a 64bit OS?